# push user location manually to piwik

Tags: matomo

I am using piwik to track my website's user interaction. The main pain point with this is I am not able to track exact user location which is very important for me.

When I use default location tracking of piwik, it shows wrong user location, may be this is because it decides user location based on the user browser language. Due to this for users from India, where mostly browser uses US English language, piwik thinks user is from USA and mislead the tracking.

I see there are different other mechanism where I can get exact user location using some IP2Location database etc.

But these doesn't work for me as for me user ip is private ip, and for which location it shows is unknown.

So I am trying to manually set the location (I have set user location in browser cookie and I want to push this data to piwik) and looking for the function/ api (_paq method) where I can manually push the Country/ state/ city etc.

Comment: Have you checked the geolocation settings in the administration interface? There you can set up which geolocation database piwik should use.

Comment: I do not want to use geolocation database as they doesn't work for internal IPs. So I am figuring out a way to push the location manually.. Something like _paq('setLocation', country, state, city)

Comment: Another thing: There is an Intranet GeoIP Plugin which allows you to Geolocate users with internal IPs:
https://plugins.piwik.org/IntranetGeoIP